# Sending mail to user with a link which should be usable only once

Tags: django, web

This is my first project in web development, I am building item reservation system using Django.

Requirement: If a user reserves an item and uses it for more than a week, a e-mail with be sent to him to re-confirm item usage.

Each e-mail will have a link which shows all the items user is using for more than a week, item would be released or continue_to_use based on user decision.

Here is the scenario, user opens the link provided in the e-mail twice(may be more), as I said each opened link will have list of items being used by him.
In "first" link, user uncheck an item and submits it and then, he will go to "second" link(which obviously contains wrong data) and will try to uncheck some item and submits it.
I want to throw an error when user submits in the "second" link, saying that you have already performed this operation.

My solution is using a field in table(user_table in database) say "link_used" and I will store "yes" when user uses "first" link and when he uses second link, code will check the 
"link_used" column and sends out error message.

This "link_used" column will reset when sending next mail.

Is my solution correct?

Googled it and didn't find solution related to my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

By doing so you will loose history and ask for run conditions.

Create separate model for links/emails similar to example below instead.

```
class OneTimeCode(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    code = models.CharField(…)
    date_sent = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, …)
    date_used = models.DateTimeField(null=True, …)

    @property
    def link_used(self):
        return self.date_used is not None
```

That way you keep history of all codes and its usages.